# I want to found I item in the ComboBox pressing keys

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

hello I had searched a lot for this question and I din't found it so I came to ask here I have this code:

```
<ComboBox TabIndex="10" x:Name="cbo_uf" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="69,76,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="52" Foreground="#FF4C63CB" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="cbo_uf_SelectionChanged" Grid.RowSpan="3" Height="23">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <TextBlock  Text="{Binding uf}" Width="50" />
             </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

To fill this ComboBox I set to the DataContext a DataTable that came from a select query sql and "uf" is the name of the column in the DataTable and it is showing normal at the ComboBox but I want that when I press some key the combobox go to the line that starts with this key like happens when I put just text in a ComboBoxItem. Sorry by my English!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like in this example:

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="true" TextSearch.TextPath="Name">
    <Image Name="Cat" Source="data\cat.png"/>
    <Image Name="Dog" Source="data\dog.png"/>
    <Image Name="Fish" Source="data\fish.png"/>
</ComboBox>
```

Code from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textsearch.textpath(v=vs.110).aspx)

Another example with Combobox.ItemTemplate

```
<ComboBox TextSearch.TextPath="Name" ItemsSource="{Binding Persons, ElementName=Window}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/de5e6589-13f2-44a4-a92b-16359932baee/textsearchtext-on-combobox-using-itemtemplate?forum=wpf)